# Using App Engine to update a database in a app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have been reading about app engine but I still dont know what I can and cant do with it in a android application.

Basically what I want to do is be able to create/manage a database in the cloud that the app can pull down and update the local database if needed. Creation and managing would be done outside of the app by me.

I dont know much about all of this as I am just getting started with it but I already have an application made, I just want to add this feature to it. I have never written any sort of Web Service calls or anything either but I have used them to get data and such

Can this be done? Any tutorials out there to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should help:

[Google I/O 2011: Android + App Engine: A Developer's Dream Combination](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U)

[Google I/O 2012 - Building Mobile App Engine Backends for Android, iOS and the Web](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU_wNR_UUn4)